# C++ 2 layers of returns in lambda functions

Tags: c++, struct, lambda

I have a piece of code, that returns the city name & population only if population is larger than 5 million.

```
#include <algorithm>
#include <iostream>
#include <iterator>
#include <vector>
using namespace std;

template <typename C>
static auto opt_print(const C& container) {
    return [end_it (end(container))] (const auto& item) {
        if (item != end_it) {
            cout << *item << endl;
        }
        else {
            cout << "<end>" << endl;
        }
    };
}

struct city {
    string name;
    unsigned population;
};

bool operator==(const city& a, const city& b) {
    return (a.name == b.name && a.population == b.population);
}

ostream& operator<<(ostream& os, const city& c) {
    return os << "{" << c.name << ", " << c.population << "}";
}

int main() {
    const vector<city> c {
        {"NYC", 8398748},
        {"LA", 3990456},
        {"Chicago", 2705994},
        {"Houston", 2325502}
    };

    auto print_city (
        opt_print(c)
    );

    auto population_more_than (
        [] (unsigned i) {
            return [=] (const city& item) {
                return (item.population > i);
            };
        }
    );
    auto found_large(
        find_if(
            begin(c),
            end(c),
            population_more_than(5000000)
        )
    );
    print_city(found_large);

    return 0;
}
```

I have the following questions:

1. What I don't understand is the lambda function `population_more_than`: why do I need 2 layers of lambda functions? Is there a way of simplifying code?
2. What does `[=]` do here? By lambda function definition, `[=]` means the accept all external variables by value, what does this `[=]` accept? Does it only take the `unsigned i` part from the outer layer?
3. If I want to change the `population_more_than` lambda function to below:

   `auto population_more_than (
       [&each_city] (unsigned i) {
           return (each_city.population > i);
       }
   );`
   How should I change the `auto found_large` lambda function part accordingly? It is already based on iterator, but I cannot get the code running...

Comment: Note: You never "need" a lambda. Lambda is just a shortcut for making a functor. You can just make functors yourself.  http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/69df532d6cb23170

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> What I don't understand is the lambda function population_more_than: why do I need 2 layers of lambda functions? Is there a way of simplifying code?

It separates passing the `int` from passing the `city`. Note that *multiple* cities are compared to the same `int` later on. `std::find_if` needs a callable like `bool(city)`, not a `bool(city, int)`

> What does [=] do here? By lambda function definition, [=] means the accept all external variables by value, what does this [=] accept? Does it only take the unsigned i part from the outer layer?

Yes.

> If I want to change the population_more_than lambda function to below: 
>   `auto population_more_than (
>       [&each_city] (unsigned i) {
>           return (each_city.population > i);
>       }
>   );` How should I change the `auto found_large` lambda function part accordingly?

`found_large` is not a lambda. It a `std::vector<city>::const_iterator`. To use `population_more_than` you would need some `int`s to call it with, and `city each_city;` defined before `population_more_than`

Answer (score 3):

You don't *need* that, but it's a way to generalize the code, capturing the limit `i` (to answer your second point). Of course you could use a simple lambda:

```
auto found_large {
    std::find_if(
        std::begin(c),
        std::end(c),
        [] (city const& item) -> bool {
            return item.population > 5'000'000;
        }
    )
};
```

The ability to better express the intent with something like `population_more_than(5'000'000)` is usually a better design choice, in the long run, though.

Answer (score 1):

1. `population_more_than` is a lambda that `return`s a lambda, in this case so that the second lambda can support different population sizes.  You don't need two levels of functions, but this does lead to a clean design since you can call `population_more_than(15)` and get a different predicate function.
2. `[=]` indeed captures local data by value.  In this case, the only variable it's going to copy is `i`, since that's the only variable you use.
3. What's `each_city`?  What do you expect `i` to be?  The current version takes a `city`, and your new version takes an `unsigned`, so there's a disconnect with how you think this is working.